# Zend Framework v1 - when I use header() in controller - redirect not work

Tags: php, zend-framework

when I use function header() in controller - redirect not work, is it normal in Zend?

Ps...
But if I add exit() after header() - this work.
And If I use $this->_redirect - is work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, this is pretty normal.

PHP frameworks like ZF1 typically create/expose a `Response` object that represents the response that your server-side application wants to send to the waiting (typically browser) client. It typically encapsulates the HTTP headers and body that you wish to send. ZF1 is probably overriding your manual `header()` call and replacing it with headers from the `Response` object. That's why your `header()` call appears effective when followed immediately by an `exit()`; you're not giving the framework a chance to use its own headers from the `Response` object.

As you appear to be aware, ZF1 controllers expose a `Redirector` action helper that can set the desired headers on this Response object and immediately send the response. For example:

```
// Get a reference to the redirector
$redirector = $this->_helper->getHelper('Redirector');

// To redirect to a given url
$redirector->gotoUrl($url);

// To redirect to a given module, controller, and action
// $controller is optional, defaults to current controller
// $module is optional, defaults to current module
$redirector->gotoSimple($action, $controller, $module);

// To redirect to a named route with specified parameters
$redirector->gotoRoute($route, $params);
```

To set HTTP response codes, as well, you can do something like:

```
$redirector->setCode(301)->setGoToUrl('/some/url')->redirectAndExit();
```

See docs for the [Redirector action helper](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.actionhelpers.html#zend.controller.actionhelpers.redirector).